# Prevent viewport from jumping to the right

Tags: cursor-movement

As soon as I put the cursor on column 79 or beyond, the Vim viewport jumps to make sure the cursor is put in the middle of the viewport. I find it massively disturbing, but could not navigate my way through the `:h` pages to find how to turn it off.

Is there some way to change what that limit is, or even disable it altogether?

Comment: What is the output of `:verbose set sidescroll? sidescrolloff?`

Comment: Ah! The output is `sidescroll=0 sidescrolloff=5`. It sounds as if one of these is the way to fix my issue.